# How to bind json data to angularJS view using $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON response from the backend that i want to display to the front end so in below case i am not able to bind `$scope` value to view.If i change response into object instead of array its populating.How to populate array object to the view ?

main.html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="workerName">Full Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="workerName" ng-model="data.firstName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="workerName">Address:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="workerName" ng-model="data.lastName">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

app.js

```
var Obj = [{firstName: "Mike", lastName:"wegner"},{firstName:"John",lastName:"Ruch"}];

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send(Obj);
});
```

workerFacotry.js

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('workerFactory', function ($http) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        getData: function(){
            return $http.get('/test');
        }
    }
});
```

workerController.js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('WorkerController', function ($scope,workerFactory) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.test = function(){
        alert("first functiona is working");
    };
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.getTestData = function(){
        workerFactory.getData().then(function(response){
            $scope.data = response.data;
            console.log("Data from server",$scope.data);
        })
    }
});
```

Json.js

```
[{
    "firstName": "Mike",
    "lastName": "wegner"
}, {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Ruch"
}]
```

Comment: Are you looping through the objects in the response in your angular frontend? All we see is one row.

Comment: this HTML doesn't match your data.  your `data` object doesn't have a `firstName` property; rather, your `data` is an array with multiple objects that have said property.  Therefore you need to iterate the array;  this is typically done by using `ng-repeat`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#!/

Comment: @mariocatch No i am not looping my whole code is in the question i am new to angular if i can get some idea how to populate value for ng-model it would be great

Comment: @Claies I want to use ng-model so i can post form with data object.

Comment: As the answer below states, you need to loop through your model, since it has more than one object in it. `ng-repeat="d in data"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the `data` using [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive as:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="d in data">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="workerName">Full Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="workerName" ng-model="d.firstName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="workerName">Address:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="workerName" ng-model="d.lastName">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want to use ng-model so i can post form values later with the data object.

Comment: `ngModel` is still used... @aftab

Comment: oh ok but is there way to populate data without ng-repeat , what changes i have to make in my controller to go for ng-model options

Comment: If you have an array of data you want to display, then you need to use `ng-repeat`. That's what it's for.

Comment: `ngRepeat` iterates over the items in your `data` array, and outputs the  `html` for each item. You could manually repeat the `html` if you know how many items you will be expecting i.e. how many names you're expecting. Then you can access `data[0].firstName` and `data[0].lastName`, etc in `ngModel`. However, I would highly recommend you familiarise yourself with both `ngModel` and `ngRepeat` and actually use `ngRepeat` for your purposes instead of manually rewriting your `html.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation i got the concept of ng-repeat.